# How to call d3.json() outside of d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a requirement that i need to refresh the d3 api which is generated through json.But i can not use location.reload() i.e i can not refresh the full page.i have a click button here that will only refresh the svg but not the ful page.Is it possible???I think that calling d3.json  from outside the script will solve the problem.Can anyone help me in that??

```
    <script>


        var w = 1200, h = 900, radius = d3.scale.log().domain([0,312000 ])
        .range([ "10", "50" ]);

        var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr("width", w).attr(
        "height", h);

        vis.append("marker")
        .attr("id", "arrowhead")
        .attr("refX", 6 + 6) /*must be smarter way to calculate shift*/
        .attr("refY", 2)
        .attr("markerWidth", 6)
        .attr("markerHeight", 4)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", "M 0,0 V 4 L6,2 Z"); //this is actual shape for arrowhead

        d3.json("LinkServlet", function(data,error) {
            var force = self.force = d3.layout.force().nodes(data.nodes).links(
            data.links).linkDistance(function(d) {
                return (d.distance * 10);
            })
            //.friction(0.5)
            .charge(-250).size([ w, h ]).start();

            var link = vis.selectAll("line.link").data(data.links).enter().append(
            "svg:line").attr("class", function(d) {
                return "link" + d.value + "";
            }).attr("x1", function(d) {
                return d.source.x;
            }).attr("y1", function(d) {
                return d.source.y;
            }).attr("x2", function(d) {
                return d.target.x;
            }).attr("y2", function(d) {
                return d.target.y;
            }).attr("marker-end", function(d) {
                if (d.value == 10 || d.value==1) {
                    return "url(#arrowhead)"
                } else {
                    return " "

           }
                ;
            });

            function openLink() {
                return function(d) {
                    var url = "";
                    if (d.slug != "") {
                        url = d.slug
                    } else if(d.type == 2) {
                        url = "clients/" + d.slug
                    } else if(d.type == 3) {
                        url = "agencies/" + d.slug
                    }
                    window.open("//" + url)
                }
            }

            var node = vis.selectAll("g.node").data(data.nodes).enter().append(
            "svg:g").attr("class", "node").call(force.drag);


            // size of the nodes are given here
            node.append("circle").attr("class", function(d) {
                return "node type" + d.type
            }).attr("r", function(d) {
                if (d.entity == "description") {
                    return 20
                } else if(d.entity=="big"){
                    return 25
                }else if(d.entity=="small"){
                    return 15
                }else if(d.entity=="company"){
                    return 25
                }else if(d.entity=="manager"){
                    return 30
                }else if(d.entity=="ceo"){
                    return 35
                }else{
                    return 18
                }
            })


            node.append("text").attr("class", function(d) {
                return "nodetext title_" + d.name
            }).attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em").style("font-size", "10px").attr(
            "text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "black").text(
            function(d) {                
                return d.name                
            });

            node.on("mouseover", function(d) {
                if (d.entity == "description") {
                    d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300).text(
                    function(d) {
                        return d.name;
                    }).style("font-size", "15px")

                } else if (d.entity == "employee") {
                    var asdf = d3.select(this);
                    asdf.select('text').remove();

                    asdf.append("text").text(function(d) {
                        return d.prefix + ' ' + d.fst_name
                    }).attr("class", "nodetext").attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .style("font-size", "5px")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white")
                    .transition().duration(300).style("font-size", "12px");

                    asdf.append("text").text(function(d) {
                        return d.snd_name
                    }).attr("class", "nodetext").attr("transform",
                    "translate(0, 12)").attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .style("font-size", "5px")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white")
                    .transition().duration(300).style("font-size", "12px");
                } else {
                    d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300)
                    .style("font-size", "15px")
                }

                if (d.entity == "company") {
                    d3.select(this).select('image').attr("width", "100px").attr("x",
                    "-46px").attr("y", "-36.5px").attr("xlink:href",
                    function(d) {
                        return d.name
                    });
                }

                if (d.entity == "company") {

                    d3.select(this).select('circle').transition().duration(300)
                    .attr("r", 28)

                } else if (d.entity == "employee") {
                    d3.select(this).select('circle').transition().duration(300)
                    .attr("r", 15)
                }
            });

            node.on("mouseout", function(d) {
                if (d.entity == "company") {
                    d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300).text(
                    function(d) {
                        return d.name;
                    }).style("font-size", "10px")
                } else if (d.entity == "employee") {
                    ///////////////////////////
                    // CHANGE
                    ///////////////////////////

                    d3.select(this).selectAll('text').remove();

                    //d3.select(this).select('text')
                    d3.select(this).append('text').text(function(d) {
                        return d.name;
                    }).style("font-size", "14px").attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white")
                    .attr("class", "nodetext").transition().duration(300)
                    .style("font-size", "10px")

                } else {
                    d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300)
                    .style("font-size", "10px")
                }

                if (d.entity == "company") {
                    d3.select(this).select('image').attr("width", "70px").attr("x",
                    "-36px").attr("y", "-36px").attr("xlink:href",
                    function(d) {
                        return d.img_hrefD
                    });
                }

                if (d.entity == "company" || d.entity == "employee") {

                    d3.select(this).select('circle').transition().duration(300)
                    .attr("r", 18)
                }

            });

            node.on("mouseover", fade(.4, "red")).on("mouseout", fade(1));

            var linkedByIndex = {};
            data.links.forEach(function(d) {
                linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
            });

            function isConnected(a, b) {
                return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index]
                    || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index]
                    || a.index == b.index;
            }

            force.on("tick", function() {
                link.attr("x1", function(d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                }).attr("y1", function(d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                }).attr("x2", function(d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                }).attr("y2", function(d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

                node.attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                });
            });


            function getConnected(cn, d, level) {
                node.each(function(o) {
                    if(isConnected(d, o) && cn.indexOf(o) == -1) {
                        cn.push(o);
                        if(level > 0) getConnected(cn, o, level-1);
                    };
                });

                return cn;
            }





            function fade(opacity,color) {
                return function(d) {

                    node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                        thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
                        this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
                        return thisOpacity;
                    });

                    link.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                        return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
                    })

                    .style("stroke", function(o) {
                        return o.source === d || o.target === d ? color : "#000" ;
                    });
                };

            }
        });
    </script>
```

sample data here

```
{"nodes":[{"name":"9748108991","type":1,"slug":"","entity":"company"},{"name":"offnet","type":2,"slug":"","entity":"employee"},{"name":"onnet","type":2,"slug":"","entity":"employee"}],"links":[{"source":0,"target":1,"value":1,"distance":10},{"source":0,"target":2,"value":1,"distance":10}]}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. There's no requirement to call `d3.json` in a specific context.

Comment: the button could trigger some JavaScript without refreshing the page

Comment: and I agree with @LarsKotthoff

Comment: i mean to say that i hava a d3 api which is populating the json data and i need to reload the api onclick on a button but the page will not refresh.Only the svg  portion on which the api is running will be refreshed

Comment: So what do you want to do ? the code is applied on the svg part

Comment: yes it is i want to refresh the svg part

Comment: can you give some sample data ?

Comment: eg an example of few data that will be there at the begginning and a few that will be given by the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that what you want to do is to just reload all the data so here is what I 've done in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agalazis/xLrsb/16/)

- I have put the d3.json in another function so that I can call it
  whenever I want to.

Now whenever I want other data:

- I use `d3.select('svg').remove();` in order to
  remove the original svg
- I call the function that includes the d3.json to visualise the new data

**EDIT**

For doing it in intervals you can use set timeout as per [my example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/agalazis/xLrsb/14/):
Your function the function that includes the d3.json code can recursively call it self in this manner:

```
 T =setTimeout(function(){
    d3.select('svg').remove();
    testing(["http://csmonk.com/data1.php","http://csmonk.com/data2.php"], ++count);
 },2000);
```

to clarify  in your case you will do:

```
    var T;// (globally)
```

in your <myd3jsonfunctionhere> function add:

```
    T =setTimeout(function() {
         d3.select('svg').remove();<myd3jsonfunctionhere>;
         },<myintervalhereinms>);
```

**More efficient(Best choice in my opinion):**

```
 window.setInterval(function(){d3.select('svg').remove();<yourd3.jsonfunctionhere>},<intervalinmilliseconds>);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLrsb/13/)**

for the last example your code should be something like:

```
</script>
    var w = 1200, h = 900, radius = d3.scale.log().domain([0,312000 ])
    .range([ "10", "50" ]);
function loadNewData(){
    var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr("width", w).attr(
    "height", h);

    vis.append("marker")
    .attr("id", "arrowhead")
    .attr("refX", 6 + 6) /*must be smarter way to calculate shift*/
    .attr("refY", 2)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 4)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M 0,0 V 4 L6,2 Z"); //this is actual shape for arrowhead

    d3.json("LinkServlet", function(data,error) {
        var force = self.force = d3.layout.force().nodes(data.nodes).links(
        data.links).linkDistance(function(d) {
            return (d.distance * 10);
        })
        //.friction(0.5)
        .charge(-250).size([ w, h ]).start();

        var link = vis.selectAll("line.link").data(data.links).enter().append(
        "svg:line").attr("class", function(d) {
            return "link" + d.value + "";
        }).attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        }).attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        }).attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        }).attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        }).attr("marker-end", function(d) {
            if (d.value == 10 || d.value==1) {
                return "url(#arrowhead)"
            } else {
                return " "

       }
            ;
        });

        function openLink() {
            return function(d) {
                var url = "";
                if (d.slug != "") {
                    url = d.slug
                } else if(d.type == 2) {
                    url = "clients/" + d.slug
                } else if(d.type == 3) {
                    url = "agencies/" + d.slug
                }
                window.open("//" + url)
            }
        }

        var node = vis.selectAll("g.node").data(data.nodes).enter().append(
        "svg:g").attr("class", "node").call(force.drag);


        // size of the nodes are given here
        node.append("circle").attr("class", function(d) {
            return "node type" + d.type
        }).attr("r", function(d) {
            if (d.entity == "description") {
                return 20
            } else if(d.entity=="big"){
                return 25
            }else if(d.entity=="small"){
                return 15
            }else if(d.entity=="company"){
                return 25
            }else if(d.entity=="manager"){
                return 30
            }else if(d.entity=="ceo"){
                return 35
            }else{
                return 18
            }
        })


        node.append("text").attr("class", function(d) {
            return "nodetext title_" + d.name
        }).attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em").style("font-size", "10px").attr(
        "text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "black").text(
        function(d) {                
            return d.name                
        });

        node.on("mouseover", function(d) {
            if (d.entity == "description") {
                d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300).text(
                function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                }).style("font-size", "15px")

            } else if (d.entity == "employee") {
                var asdf = d3.select(this);
                asdf.select('text').remove();

                asdf.append("text").text(function(d) {
                    return d.prefix + ' ' + d.fst_name
                }).attr("class", "nodetext").attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em")
                .style("font-size", "5px")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white")
                .transition().duration(300).style("font-size", "12px");

                asdf.append("text").text(function(d) {
                    return d.snd_name
                }).attr("class", "nodetext").attr("transform",
                "translate(0, 12)").attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em")
                .style("font-size", "5px")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white")
                .transition().duration(300).style("font-size", "12px");
            } else {
                d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300)
                .style("font-size", "15px")
            }

            if (d.entity == "company") {
                d3.select(this).select('image').attr("width", "100px").attr("x",
                "-46px").attr("y", "-36.5px").attr("xlink:href",
                function(d) {
                    return d.name
                });
            }

            if (d.entity == "company") {

                d3.select(this).select('circle').transition().duration(300)
                .attr("r", 28)

            } else if (d.entity == "employee") {
                d3.select(this).select('circle').transition().duration(300)
                .attr("r", 15)
            }
        });

        node.on("mouseout", function(d) {
            if (d.entity == "company") {
                d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300).text(
                function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                }).style("font-size", "10px")
            } else if (d.entity == "employee") {
                ///////////////////////////
                // CHANGE
                ///////////////////////////

                d3.select(this).selectAll('text').remove();

                //d3.select(this).select('text')
                d3.select(this).append('text').text(function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                }).style("font-size", "14px").attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white")
                .attr("class", "nodetext").transition().duration(300)
                .style("font-size", "10px")

            } else {
                d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300)
                .style("font-size", "10px")
            }

            if (d.entity == "company") {
                d3.select(this).select('image').attr("width", "70px").attr("x",
                "-36px").attr("y", "-36px").attr("xlink:href",
                function(d) {
                    return d.img_hrefD
                });
            }

            if (d.entity == "company" || d.entity == "employee") {

                d3.select(this).select('circle').transition().duration(300)
                .attr("r", 18)
            }

        });

        node.on("mouseover", fade(.4, "red")).on("mouseout", fade(1));

        var linkedByIndex = {};
        data.links.forEach(function(d) {
            linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
        });

        function isConnected(a, b) {
            return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index]
                || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index]
                || a.index == b.index;
        }

        force.on("tick", function() {
            link.attr("x1", function(d) {
                return d.source.x;
            }).attr("y1", function(d) {
                return d.source.y;
            }).attr("x2", function(d) {
                return d.target.x;
            }).attr("y2", function(d) {
                return d.target.y;
            });

            node.attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
            });
        });


        function getConnected(cn, d, level) {
            node.each(function(o) {
                if(isConnected(d, o) && cn.indexOf(o) == -1) {
                    cn.push(o);
                    if(level > 0) getConnected(cn, o, level-1);
                };
            });

            return cn;
        }





        function fade(opacity,color) {
            return function(d) {

                node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                    thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
                    this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
                    return thisOpacity;
                });

                link.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                    return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
                })

                .style("stroke", function(o) {
                    return o.source === d || o.target === d ? color : "#000" ;
                });
            };

        }
    });
 }
 loadNewData();
 window.setInterval(function(){d3.select('svg').remove();loadNewData()},5000);
</script>
```

Comment: can you tell me one thing that in this example you have used a .php file to load data firstly and then d3.select('svg').remove(); to load another svg write?so when i put a servlet in the place of d3.json() as i used in this question then where should i put this remove  thing?i.e you have use link from an external source

Comment: I have done it by interchanging the links but your servlet might serve different data as the time passes so you may be calling the same link in intervals

Comment: sorry, reposting the comment before the above as I posted the wrong link: you can load data in intevals as in my example in this [new example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLrsb/8/) calls the d3.select('svg').remove(); and my testing function which includes the d3.json every 5 seconds

Comment: Also window.setInterval is a better choice ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLrsb/11/))

Comment: onclick="d3.select('svg').remove();"JsonServlet";$(this).remove();" is this not working can you help me in Servlet calling

Comment: yes what you forgot is to call you d3json wrapper function to do this I called testing(<uri_array here>) you don't simply call ramove and then put a string uri you just call your function which does the d3.json part (which I called testing in my case - Alsoin my case the function was accepting a uri array for the json but in your case you can have it hard coded). Also you want to do it in intervals you can use window.setInterval as in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLrsb/8/)

Comment: just added how the code in your case should be in the case of the interval you can see how I call the `loadNewData()` function in the last lines

Answer (score 0):

The button could trigger some JavaScript without refreshing the page if you want to filter your data you can take a look into [crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) or use a library that leverages it like [dc.js](http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/)